# How to load png image in qml from an absolute path?

Tags: image, url, qml

I have a problem trying to load an image from an absolute path from qml. (from a relative path everything goes well)

```
Image {
    id : myimage

    source: qsTr("qrc:///")+imagePath
}
```

My image path is a well defined windows path.
I tried many suggestions that I found while googling:
Like starting with `file:///` or with `qrc:///`
Nothing I found worked. It can not load the image.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Side note: You do not need to use qsTr() around "qrc:///". That string shouldn't need to change languages.

Comment: Only use "qrc:///" if your image is coming from a resource file. For files coming from the filesystem use "file:///". *"my image path is a well defined windows path"* -- Can you be more specific? What exactly are you trying to set imagePath to? Without seeing the real string, we can't tell if there is a mistake in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute path you'll want to be using is formatted as a URI like documented here:
[Windows File URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows)

Try something like:
source: "file:///c:/mypath/myimage.png"